# How to keep filebeat registry

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat

I need to move my filebeat to other namespace, but I must keep registry , I mean that:

```
 # data folder stores a registry of read status for all files, so we don't send everything again on a Filebeat pod restart
      - name: data
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/filebeat-data
          type: DirectoryOrCreate
```

Can you tell me how can I copy that in kubernetes

Comment: Did you try to use `kubectl cp` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to check my assumptions:

- filebeat is a a DaemonSet
- When you start it up in the new Namespace, you want to keep the registry
- You're happy to keep the on-disk path the same

Because the `data` folder is mounted from the host directly - if you apply the same DaemonSet in a new Namespace, it will mount the same location into the container. So there's no need to copy any files around.